# Set firefox profile from profile available and load extension protractor

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor, geckodriver

I have a code set firefox profile from local

```
var makeFirefoxProfile = function (preferenceMap) {
  var firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile("C:/Users/tam/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/avbq6r8s.TamVo");
  for (var key in preferenceMap) {
    firefoxProfile.setPreference(key, preferenceMap[key]);
  }
  var firefoxIntegrationFile = "./extension/firefox_integration/sample.xpi";
  firefoxProfile.addExtension(firefoxIntegrationFile);
  return q.resolve({
    browserName: 'firefox',
    marionette: true,
    firefox_profile: firefoxProfile
  });
};
```

So it cannot load profile from local and .xpi extension. I remove profile path, remove addExtension, it set profile correctly.

How I can do that?